# The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to resolve the problem described here:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4757
by building selenium standalone server locally, after some edits. And after release a get local version of selenium standalone server "selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta1.jar", and it runs. But when I'm trying to connect to server from protractor or from selenium builder I get error:

"WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/jgraham"

How to integrate (or do something) to get selenium standalone serer with integrated firefox driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way which worked for me was to clone sources from github by using GIT. Earlier i downloaded zip and it doesn't work, then I clone sources by sunig GIT and do all steps described here: http://shengwangi.blogspot.ru/2014/08/how-to-build-selenium-from-source.html, except "Download 3rd party library" step.