# error: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, phpstorm

I am working on an automated functional unit testing in PHP. I want to run a test on staging environment using PhpStorm and I am following this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/. I have complete tasks up-to this code :
i have visited this link but not work for me. [The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728434/the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-gecko-driver-syst)

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Developer4
 * Date: 11/2/2016
 * Time: 1:41 PM
 */
class uatTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowserUrl('https://www.facebook.com/');

        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    }
    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->stop();
    }
    public function validInputsProvider()
    {
        $inputs[] = [
            [
                'email'              => 'user',
                'pass'              => 'pass'
            ]
        ];
        return $inputs;
    }
    public function testFormSubmissionWithUsername()
    {
        $this->byName('email')->value('user');
        $this->byId('loginbutton')->submit();
        $email = $this->byName('email');
        $this->assertEquals('user', $email->value());
    }
}
```

as my selenium server is running: [image]

when i have run my test on phpstorm i get this error
[image]

Error:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:/wamp/www/PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration uatTest C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\test\uatTest.php --teamcity
Testing started at 2:53 PM ...
PHPUnit 5.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php:165
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php:72
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\SessionStrategy\Isolated.php:67
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:296
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:337
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:314



Time: 823 ms, Memory: 3.50MB


ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

and also get exeception on cmd: [image]

Answer (score 3):

this is solution:

```
    java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Users\Developer4\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32\geckodriver.exe" -jar C:\wamp\bin\php

\php5.6.25\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```